# How to evaluate lassoCV and ridgeCV (package chemometrics)

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, evaluation, lasso-regression

I use the R functions lassoCV and ridgeCV to train models as described in the documentation and vignette, but I am still unsure how to evaluate it.

Both functions use cross-validation and calculate MSE/RMSE, SEP etc. Can I use these MSE/RMSE, SEP etc. values directly for evaluation or should I use e.g. just 90% of the data for lassoCV and ridgeCV, train the models and than in a second step: extract the best model and evaluate it on the remaining 10% of the data again?

To me, the description looks like the use of just lassoCV and ridgeCV is sufficient. Therefore it's not necessary separating the data into training and test data, since this is already done by lassoCV and ridgeCV. But, am I right/is this really the truth? Do the resulting MSE/RMSE etc. values really come from just training data? Respectively is the training strictly/sufficient separated from the evaluation?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you seek recommendations for evaluating statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] or [datascience.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: The quality of fit on the validation set will be slightly inflated because you selected the hyperparameters that produced the best fit on that particular validation set.  In a way, the validation set was used as part of the tuning. In practice, I think you'll find that the test set quality of fit is usually not too different from the validation set, but "train-validate-test" is the best practice for evaluating model error.